# Customizing PS1 for two rows similar to zsh Kali

Tags: terminal, zsh

I was hoping someone might be able to help me figure out how I can customize my PS1 on macOS zsh to look like Kali zsh.

Here is $PS1 from Kali zsh:

```
%F{%(#.blue.green)}┌──${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)─}${VIRTUAL_ENV:+($(basename $VIRTUAL_ENV))─}(%B%F{%(#.red.blue)}%n$prompt_symbol%m%b%F{%(#.blue.green)})-[%B%F{reset}%(6~.%-1~/…/%4~.%5~)%b%F{%(#.blue.green)}]
└─%B%(#.%F{red}#.%F{blue}$)%b%F{reset}
```

And, of course, here is $PS1 from macOS zsh:

```
%n@%m %1~ %#
```

I'm kind of hung up on this area

```
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)─}${VIRTUAL_ENV:+($(basename $VIRTUAL_ENV))─}
```

And lastly I'm a little concerned that if I remove those obviously Linux parts of the PS1, without fully understanding how they behave and do not realize I need to replace them in kind with something macOS compatible, that I'm going nowhere fast.

This PS1, as-is, is clearly not going to fly in macOS but there are several other parts in the Kali PS1 that make me believe that simply deleting that stuff or not removing other stuff might mess things up royally.

If anyone could be so kind I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You may want to start with `man zsh` to figure out what `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)─}` does. Or, as Tony pointet out in the answer already, focus on what your prompt on macOS should look like and build it from scratch.

Comment: You might look at `man zshmisc` and `man zshcontrib`. In both cases, search for the string "PROMPT".

Answer (score 1):

Prompt hacking is an art and usually requires a lot of practice and effort.

If you want to get a better PS1 prompt you might be advised to install a zsh plug-in manager and have a look at some themes. I personally use the [ohmyzsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) plug-in manager with the [PowerLevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) theme that allows for a bunch of ways of customising the prompt.

Otherwise, update your question with a picture of the prompt you like and we can see about helping you. What exactly do you want in your prompt?

Comment: thank you very much i had no idea there were themes, i settled on "bira" theme from the wiki in the link you provided. its a compromise in some ways but better in others. it does have the full current working directory along with the user/hostname in the top row (along git integration with git integration which is a major plus) i think i'll keep it with this.